# Where/how can I find out about public breastfeeding facilities?

Tags: breastfeeding, family-activities

My wife and I were going to plan our first family outing with our newborn. The easiest way for us to breastfeed is still with the breastfeeding pillow and a chair. So no hooter hiders quite yet and my wife is modest about whipping 'em out in public. We're trying to figure out online where/what stores might offer breastfeeding facilities. My google-fu is failing me.  Is there some place/way to find out (in the US) where we can breastfeed? Is there some common signage or online place where breastfeeding locations can be easily located so you can plan your day around feedings?

Comment: The only stores I've noticed that offer private breastfeeding facilities are the ones tailored specifically to maternity (Motherhood, for example).

Comment: @Beofett I've heard that Nordstrom has facilities, which made me wonder whether there's some way I can know if where we're going will have them

Comment: Ikea is very family friendly with kid-sized toilets, change tables, and supplies! They often have private rooms for nursing, complete with rocking chairs.

Comment: My wife loves the baby rooms in art museums here in Seattle.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how complete their database is, but [**this iPhone app**](http://www.medelabreastfeedingus.com/whats-new/128/medela-goes-mobile) provides a database of public locations with comments:

#### [New Medela iPhone App Helps Breastfeeding Moms](http://nursingbling.com/2011/02/01/new-medela-iphone-app-helps-breastfeeding-moms/)

> With the Breastfeeding-Friendly Places feature, on-the-go moms can quickly locate a clean, comfortable place to breastfeed or breastpump. Driven by GPS navigation and Google Maps, the locator will include Medela reviewed and approved locations nationwide.  Moms can also submit their favorite public locations for breastfeeding and include comments.

Comment: Do you know if this database is accessible without an iphone through a web interface? I checked the Medela site, but nothing obvious pops out at me.

Comment: My wife tried this app out and it was basically useless for Seattle. Instead of a database of places to breastfeed it was a database of places to buy Medela stuff which I guess might also be good places to breastfeed, but there were none in downtown Seattle. An app with user generated content would probably be best for this, I hope someone writes one.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK it is illegal to discriminate against women who wish to breastfeed.  So, if your wife was not shy about whipping them out in public she could go into any (open to public) business and feed.

Most places will have some kind of baby-changing room.  They sometimes have seats suitable for feeding.  As you can imagine, it's not the nicest place to feed a baby.

Comment: It's also illegal to forbid breastfeeding in the US; even so, it's very common for nosy strangers with no tie to the business whatsoever to come up to complain and criticize. That can be an uncomfortable hurdle to overcome, although practice, overfull breasts, and an hungry/angry baby are helpful incentives. However, it's also worth noting that I've had many supportive comments from random strangers as well :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the modern world is not educated enough to consider breastfeeding in public as a natural process and the breastfeeding woman may expect the criticism of the strangers. No matter, how resistant to a public opinion you are - it may still influence the sacred process. Thus, the intervention of the observers may be a significant disadvantage of public breastfeeding: [the pros and cons of breastfeeding in public](http://motherhow.com/breastfeeding-in-public-the-pros-and-cons/)

Answer (score 1):

My wife's cousin just recently gave birth 5 months ago but is now back to work. She says she breastfeeds when out with the infant and pumps when at work. She said she recently found a mobile website through a Facebook moms group called MomsPumpHere (http://www.momspumphere.com/places/list/all) that loads a huge list of places in your specific city or state, where moms can breastfeed or breast pump when moving around.